# ADODB doesn't raise SQL errors in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I've noticed that when a query is run in VBA, VBA doesn't always inform errors raised by it. For example if I try to do a bulk insert with a null value in a row that doesn't accept nulls I get this error in SQL Server:

```
Msg 4869, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The bulk load failed. Unexpected NULL value in data file row 2, column 7. The destination column (IFSFxRate) is defined as NOT NULL.
```

However it doesn't raise any errors when I execute it with ADODB, though I noticed that if I do rs.NextRecordset I get an debug window with the error message.

```
Public Sub ExecuteQuery(sql As String)    Dim Error As ADODB.Error
    Dim Error As ADODB.Error
    Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Conn.CommandTimeout = 0
    Call Conn.Open(ConfigFactory.DB_CONNECTION)
    Set rs = Conn.Execute(sql) ' "raiserror ('xyz', 10, 127)"
    Debug.Print Conn.Errors.Count ' Returns 0
    rs.NextRecordset ' The bulk load failed. Unexpected NULL value in data file row 2
    Connection.Close
    Set Connection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Why is the error not raised on .Execute? Is there something I can do to get the log in these cases?

Comment: Have you set `On Error Resume Next` ?

Comment: no, that's the whole code. It does notify of some errors, I've been reading a bit and there seem to be bugs with SQL Server and errors during bulk inserts. However I added an user defined error and still I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server with ADO will generate a recordset for every "result set" which is returned.

That is, for every statement in the batch which either produces a "rows affected" output or an output rowset. You must use `Set rs = rs.NextRecordSet` to page through the results.

Each error is attached to an individual statement, so they will may not be processed on the client, (and added to the `Connection` object) until you reach that resultset of that statement.

Generally you won't be interested in empty resultsets, so you will see your code sprinkled with this:

```
While rs.EOF Do
  Debug.Print "Empty Recordset with " & rs.RecordCount & " rows affected"
  Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
Next
```

If you are interested, you can get the "rows affected" information by consulting the `RecordCount` property as above.

Alternatively, you can suppress the empty recordsets by using `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your SQL statement (or stored procedure).

Comment: just for people having the same problem, SET NOCOUNT ON did the trick. I wasn't able to get multiple RecordSets and use the NextRecordset method though.